# Single error iterated but almost fully successful array_combine: Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean

Tags: php, csv, error-handling, array-combine

[Here is](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qjthgkpany1kvh/AuscompDataFeed.csv?dl=0) the full csv file to which this problem pertains.

I don't understand how the error

> Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kalugi\auscomp\test.php on line 18

applies in this case, to:

```
<?php
    // Set header
    function set_header($csv_input, $html_preview) {
        $file = fopen($csv_input, "r");
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $csv_array[] = fgetcsv($file);
        }
        $header = array_shift($csv_array);
        foreach ($csv_array as $product) {
            $headered_array[] = array_combine($header, $product);
        }
        //print_r
        if ($html_preview = 'y') {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($headered_array);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }

    set_header('ACDataFeed.csv', 'y');
```

```
Edit: Every iteration of `print_r($header); print_r($product);` within foreach() loop reveals that both are arrays of the same size:

        Array
    (
        [0] => No_
        [1] => Manufacturer ID
        [2] => Description
        [3] => LQ Price
        [4] => Retail Price Incl_ GST
        [5] => AvailableQty
        [6] => Rocklea
        [7] => Sydney
        [8] => Net Weight
        [9] => Item Category Code
        [10] => Product Group Code
        [11] => Minor Category 1
        [12] => Minor Category 2
        [13] => Vendor Name
        [14] => Vendor URL
        [15] => Item URL
        [16] => Warranty
        [17] => Dimension
        [18] => Description1
        [19] => Image
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => II00570
        [1] => AUSC00008
        [2] => GNR CAB USB-A-B-5M
        [3] => 6.00000000000000000000
        [4] => 18.00000000000000000000
        [5] => 2.00000000000000000000
        [6] => 1.00000000000000000000
        [7] => 1.00000000000000000000
        [8] => 0.01000000000000000000
        [9] => GNR
        [10] => CAB
        [11] => CAB-USB
        [12] => #
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
        [15] => 
        [16] => 
        [17] => 
        [18] => Generic USB2.0 A-Male to B-Male Printer Cable - 5m

        [19] => https://accomputers.com/uploads/image/GNR-CAB-USB-A-B-5M.jpg
    )

I've considered this through and I'm geniunely unable to see the error here.  How is this false for an array?
```

Edit 2: Yet the `array_combine` is successful, despite the error appearing above it.  You can see that array `$header` was successfully combined with array `$product` below, despite the error:

```
Warning: array_combine() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kalugi\auscomp\test.php on line 18

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [No_] => II00570
            [Manufacturer ID] => AUSC00008
            [Description] => GNR CAB USB-A-B-5M
            [LQ Price] => 6.00000000000000000000
            [Retail Price Incl_ GST] => 18.00000000000000000000
            [AvailableQty] => 2.00000000000000000000
            [Rocklea] => 1.00000000000000000000
            [Sydney] => 1.00000000000000000000
            [Net Weight] => 0.01000000000000000000
            [Item Category Code] => GNR
            [Product Group Code] => CAB
            [Minor Category 1] => CAB-USB
            [Minor Category 2] => #
            [Vendor Name] => 
            [Vendor URL] => 
            [Item URL] => 
            [Warranty] => 
            [Dimension] => 
            [Description1] => Generic USB2.0 A-Male to B-Male Printer Cable - 5m

            [Image] => https://auscompcomputers.com/uploads/image/GNR-CAB-USB-A-B-5M.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [No_] => II00693
            [Manufacturer ID] => M6
            [Description] => ITR KBD M6-PS2-WHT
            [LQ Price] => 8.50000000000000000000
            [Retail Price Incl_ GST] => 24.00000000000000000000
            [AvailableQty] => 202.00000000000000000000
            [Rocklea] => 200.00000000000000000000
            [Sydney] => 2.00000000000000000000
            [Net Weight] => 0.50000000000000000000
            [Item Category Code] => ITR
            [Product Group Code] => KBD
            [Minor Category 1] => KBD-WIRED
            [Minor Category 2] => KBD-SINGLE
            [Vendor Name] => 
            [Vendor URL] => 
            [Item URL] => 
            [Warranty] => 
            [Dimension] => 
            [Description1] => Itron M6 Keyboard, PS2 Beige

            [Image] => https://auscompcomputers.com/uploads/image/ITR-KBD-M6-PS2-WHT.jpg
        )
```

For completeness, here is the debugging output for:

```
foreach($csv_array as $product) {
//      $csv_array[][1]
        $headered_array[] = array_combine($header,$product);
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($header);
        var_dump($product);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

The var_dumps:

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "No_"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "Manufacturer ID"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "Description"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "LQ Price"
  [4]=>
  string(22) "Retail Price Incl_ GST"
  [5]=>
  string(12) "AvailableQty"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "Rocklea"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "Sydney"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "Net Weight"
  [9]=>
  string(18) "Item Category Code"
  [10]=>
  string(18) "Product Group Code"
  [11]=>
  string(16) "Minor Category 1"
  [12]=>
  string(16) "Minor Category 2"
  [13]=>
  string(11) "Vendor Name"
  [14]=>
  string(10) "Vendor URL"
  [15]=>
  string(8) "Item URL"
  [16]=>
  string(8) "Warranty"
  [17]=>
  string(9) "Dimension"
  [18]=>
  string(12) "Description1"
  [19]=>
  string(5) "Image"
}
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "II00570"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "AUSC00008"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "GNR CAB USB-A-B-5M"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "6.00000000000000000000"
  [4]=>
  string(23) "18.00000000000000000000"
  [5]=>
  string(22) "2.00000000000000000000"
  [6]=>
  string(22) "1.00000000000000000000"
  [7]=>
  string(22) "1.00000000000000000000"
  [8]=>
  string(22) "0.01000000000000000000"
  [9]=>
  string(3) "GNR"
  [10]=>
  string(3) "CAB"
  [11]=>
  string(7) "CAB-USB"
  [12]=>
  string(1) "#"
  [13]=>
  string(0) ""
  [14]=>
  string(0) ""
  [15]=>
  string(0) ""
  [16]=>
  string(0) ""
  [17]=>
  string(0) ""
  [18]=>
  string(56) "Generic USB2.0 A-Male to B-Male Printer Cable - 5m
"
  [19]=>
  string(65) "https://auscompcomputers.com/uploads/image/GNR-CAB-USB-A-B-5M.jpg"
}
```

Comment: you're probably passing a Boolean instead of an array.

Comment: what `var_dump()` says for both `$header` and `$product` within your `foreach()`?

Comment: @mitkosoft see OP - I have appended on example iteration of the output for  `print_r($header); print_r($product); within foreach() loop`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [array\_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459112/array-combine-expects-parameter-1-to-be-array-string-given)

Comment: @Dilek It's a good question and answer, but I don't use `array_map` at all like the question asker?

Comment: @user136649, is this error appears on every iteration, or just once? could you please define `$iterator` counter out of your `foreach()`, increment it with 1 inside then echo and debug the arrays on every iteration? I truly believe that you have an extra new line into your file which produce an empty `$product` array member.

Comment: So what I did was: `foreach($csv_array as $product) {
        $headered_array[] = array_combine($header,$product);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($header);
  print_r($product);
  echo '</pre>';
 }`.  So it's printing arrays correctly for every iteration of the foreach loop.  In the original code, the error only appears once.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @user136649, could you please share both arrays when the error appears?

Comment: See Edit 2 in original post: After the error appears once, the entire successfully array_combined result follows.  So the `array_combine` is successful despite the error.

Comment: @user136649 Link I gave is about `array_combine();`,  anyway can you try like this please without `array_shift();`
        `$header = $csv_array;
        foreach ($csv_array as $product) {
            $headered_array = array_combine($header, $product);`

Comment: @Dilek The question you linked is indeed about `array_combine` but the asker's problem was different, as he was also using `array_map` in his code and that turned out to be the problem.  Anyway, `$header = $csv_array; foreach ($csv_array as $product) { $headered_array = array_combine($header, $product);}` gives `Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in C:\xampp\htdocs\kalugi\auscomp\test.php on line 28`

Comment: @Dilek - here is the full csv file, why don't you try yourself: [download here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qjthgkpany1kvh/AuscompDataFeed.csv?dl=0)

Comment: I think I solved it guys.  Upvote if you like my solution because I got slammed earlier with downvotes and it turned out to be an instructive question and answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a really good question as you'll see in the following solution.

It's a common pitfall of csv files that a redundant line terminator at the end actually causes an empty array to be written when using PHP's inbuilt csv-to-array functions such as fgetcsv, which are very basic and do not take such things into account.

From PHP Manual for [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

> 5.4.0 Previous versions issued E_WARNING and returned FALSE for empty arrays.

This matches the fact that the error was only returned *once* for the whole foreach loop that was compiling the array, since there was only one empty array at the end of the csv file.  It also explains why the `array_combined` actually succeeded with all but the last element case.

See that last array is empty:

```
...
    [8405] => Array
        (
            [No_] => II38392
            [Manufacturer ID] => 7XB7A00034
            [Description] => LEN HDD SAS-1TB-7XB7A00034
            [LQ Price] => 336.00000000000000000000
            [Retail Price Incl_ GST] => 480.48000000000000000000
            [AvailableQty] => 0.00000000000000000000
            [Rocklea] => 
            [Sydney] => 
            [Net Weight] => 0.50000000000000000000
            [Item Category Code] => LEN
            [Product Group Code] => HDD
            [Minor Category 1] => HDD-2.5
            [Minor Category 2] => HDD-ENT
            [Vendor Name] => Lenovo
            [Vendor URL] => 
            [Item URL] => 
            [Warranty] => 3 Years
            [Dimension] => 
            [Description1] => Lenovo 7XB7A00034, ThinkSystem 2.5" 1TB 7.2K SAS 12Gb Hot Swap 512n HDD, 3 Years

            [Image] => https://auscompcomputers.com/uploads/image/LEN-HDD-SAS-1TB-7XB7A00034.jpg
        )

    [8406] => 
    )
```

Solution - treat the file first before passing it into any further functions:

```
function remove_last_n($csv_input){
    //remove the very last newline to prevent a 0-field array for the last line
    $str = file_get_contents($csv_input);
    $str = preg_replace('/\n$/', '', $str);
    file_put_contents("$csv_input",$str);
}
remove_last_n('whatever_file.csv');
```

Answer (score 0):

See user136649's explanation.

in my case I need the array before putting it into a file, so I did the following and checked for the last empty row

```
$stream = fopen('filepath', 'r');
if ($stream) {
    $header = [];
    $count = 0;
    while (!feof($stream)) {
        $row = fgetcsv($stream, 0, ';');
        if (empty($header)) {
            $header = $row;
        } elseif (empty($row)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
    }
} else {
    throw new Exception($stream . ' doesn`t exist or is not readable.');
}
fclose($stream);
```